# Changing the value of a variable through user input and re-using it on a different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

First I would like to say that I searched and found plenty of answers and even tried a couple (more than...) but to no avail! The error is probably mine but it is time to turn to SO and ask.

Problem description: I have a variable that I want to change the value through the user input (click on btn). As soon as the user chooses the btn it will navigate to a different page that will use the result of the variable to perform certain actions. My issue is that if I alert on my 1st page I get the value being passed by the btn... But on the second page I only get "undefined"

I think it has to do with variable scope and the fact that (I think it works that way anyway) even a window.var will be deleted/purged in a different window.

Anyway, the code is something like this (on the 1st page/file):

```
var somAlvo;

$('#omissL').click(function(){
    somAlvo = 'l';
    window.location.href='index_ProofOfConcept_nivel1.html';
});
```

And on the "receiving end" I have the following code

```
<head>
 ...
<script type="text/javascript" src="testForm_javascript.js"></script>
```

to "import" the js file with the variable and:

```
var processo = somAlvo;
alert(processo);
```

I tried declaring window, not using var inside the function and so on...
This is a proof of Concept for a project in my local University, where I'm working as a research assistant (so, this is not homework ;) )

Thanks for any help/hints...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in that when you navigate to another page, the entire JavaScript runtime is reset and all variables lost.

To preserve a value across page loads you have two options:

- Include it as part of a query string when navigating to the new page.
- Set a cookie.

You may also want to look into loading the new content through an AJAX call and replacing what is displayed. This way you won't reload the entire page which won't cause the JavaScript runtime to be reset.

Comment: Thanks Anders! I cannot give +1 to you yet (or haven't found the way to do it) but you really pointed me to the right direction. I'll try to test those ideas today. I'm thinking that if I implement local Storage (session maybe) I can deal with this and another issue I had to do! ;) Thanks again!

Comment: You'll have to gain at least 15 reputation before you can upvote. But you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark. That will earn me 15 rep and you will get 2 rep.

Comment: Checked ;) And if someone stumbles upon this question, I did ended up solving it following Anders recommendation and set up a local Storage to keep my variable value across!